# Video streaming in Drupal

Tags: video, drupal-7, streaming

I used [`Media Front`](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront) module to stream video in `Drupal 7` with Open Standards Media Player after setting up presets in admin

I can able to run very few `mp4` files. Do i need to install any streaming application ?

Comment: share your drupal module. hope its drupal 7 !

Comment: @Venkatraman : The module used is MediaFront URL :https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront

Comment: Install your module here, http://www.opensourcecms.com/demo/2/183/Drupal credential: admin/demo123 and share the issue

Comment: @venkatraman: added video in above mentioned url, after adding video, trying to stream , but not works

Comment: its demo site. got deleted now. share the current url. will proceed further once you shared

Comment: @Venkatraman Works fine in shared server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my answer to under the Mediafront.

#### What is MediaFront ?

The MediaFront module is a front end media solution for Drupal.

It employs an innovative and intuitive administration interface that allows the website administrator to completely customize the front end media experience for their users without writing any code.

#### Below dependencies libraries need to be added and make sure it been included without an error.

It requires [Open Standard Media (OSM) Player](http://www.mediafront.org/project/osmplayer)
It requires [minPlayer](http://github.com/travist/minplayer)
It requires [jQuery-UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller)

#### Try below to see how it works !

```
<!-- Include the core jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the core media player JavaScript. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="osmplayer/bin/osmplayer.compressed.js"></script>

<!-- Include the DarkHive ThemeRoller jQuery UI theme. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="osmplayer/jquery-ui/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Include the Default template CSS and JavaScript. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="osmplayer/templates/default/css/osmplayer_default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="osmplayer/templates/default/osmplayer.default.js"></script>
```

#### Calling the OSM Player

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("video").osmplayer({
      width: '100%',
      height: '600px'
    });
  });
</script>
<video src="http://progressive.totaleclips.com.edgesuite.net/105/e105598_257.mp4" poster="http://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/143/MPW-71686"></video>
```